# How to access and query call history log in both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm currently developing an iOS and Android app in Flutter. How can I access call history log.

Comment: You cannot access the call history on iOS. It is private data

Answer (score 0):

For android, only dialer and caller id related application can access call log data. Google doesn't allow others application to access this data.